# Enabling SASS on a basic HTML/CSS site

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

Want to take my first look at SASS. How can I convert a basic CSS into SASS, is it just a case of adjusting my  link and then transferring to a .sass extension. Then editing the SASS content?

Just got a simple HTML/CSS site to do some testing.
Do I need Ruby or any extra server config to get SASS setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to install sass first! If you are on a mac, enter the following to the terminal:

```
sudo gem install sass
```

When you have installed it, go to your project folder (in the terminal), and create a file with the .scss extension.

Then, in the terminal, enter the following:

```
sass --watch styles.scss:styles.css
```

(styles.scss being the name of your scss/sass file, whatever you named it).

What this does is that it saves all your sass code that you have in your .scss file into a normal .css file. Then in your html, link up it to use the .css file, not the .scss file. (as the .css file has everything you had in your .scss file, but converted to a format it can read).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm on a Windows PC, so I assuem that command would work locally but I assume my host will need SSH if I am going to install SASS. So standard web hosting without shell access wouldn't do (no way to install/build files manually?)

Comment: Well the webhosting has nothing to do with you sass files if you do it this way. When you upload your files, you just upload the .css file, as it has already been converted from sass locally. You are writing sass, and converting it into normal .css automatically with the sass --watch command. You can read more about how to install sass on a windows computer here: http://sass-lang.com/install

Comment: So put all my CSS code in the scss file (it is working, but the style.css which I am linking to in my <head> is blank?

Comment: Yes, all your css code in a .scss file (you can use the sass rules in this file), and your style.css file is blank UNTIL you use the sass --watch styles.scss:styles.css command, which converts the things you have written in your scss file to your empty css file!

Comment: Ok thanks matmik. that makes sense now, lastly if my hosting didn't have SSH i assume SASS isn't an option?

Comment: It doesnt matter if the hosting has SSH, because you are only uploading a normal .css file. You dont upload the .scss file to your hosting. If your hosting can host normal .css, then you are okay! So what you upload to your server/host: your .html, .css files. No .scss, because they are converted on your computer to the .css file BEFORE you upload.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is compiled from SASS, so you'll need a compiler of some sort. You can install the SASS gem as indicated by @matmik above, or you can use a tool like CodeKit on the Mac. CodeKit provides a GUI to command line which may be better if you're a beginner.

An example of SASS precompiled looks like this:

```
.intro {
  padding: 1% 1.5% 2%;
  background-color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  p {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
  }
}
```

Note that you can nest elements which greatly reduces the amount of code you write by hand. This is just one of the great things about SASS. Anyway, this is what the compiled CSS looks like:

```
.intro {
  padding: 1% 1.5% 2%;
  background-color: #555;
  text-align: center;
}
.intro h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.intro p {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of tools to the job for you.

- [css2scss](http://sebastianpontow.de/css2compass/)
- [csspre](https://csspre.com/convert/)

Sample CSS:

```
.alert {color: red;}
```

SCSS:

```
//colors
$red: red;

.alert {
    color: $red;
}
```